# Google App Engine - Request class query_string

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In Python and GAE, I would like to ask how to get the parameters of a query string in the url. 
As I know, the  query_string part returns all the part after the "?" in the url. So what I have to do is to split the query string with "&", and use the variables.
Is there any other convinient way to manage the query string?
How do you normally do it?

```
str_query = self.request.query_string
m = str_query.split('&')
a = m[0] 
b = m[1]
c = m[2]
```

Doing this way, in case, the query_string does not have any values, it threw an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to complicate. You can retrieve all GET parameters with:

```
self.request.get('var_name')
```

Or if you want to retrieve them all in one list you can use:

```
self.request.get_all()
```

You can find more info on the Request class [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_get_all).

Comment: self.request.get_all() doesn't actually work without a parameter; it doesn't return all the query variables, it just returns all the values of a particular variable.  For the complete list you need to use self.request.arguments().

Comment: As @apenwarr says, this is no longer a valid answer: `get_all` needs a parameter name to get all values for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over all the parameters of your request, you should do something like this:

```
for argument in self.request.arguments():
    values = self.request.get_all(argument)
    # do something with values (which is a list)
```

Or, you could build your own `dict` containing all the data:

```
params = {arg: self.request.get_all(arg) for arg in self.request.arguments()}
```